# RPM Spec files: Set %config files from a list of files

Tags: centos7, rpm, specfile

Example snippet of a SPEC file:

```
...    
%install
unzip $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/APPLICATION-%{version}.zip -d %{buildroot}/
find %{buildroot} -type f ! -name "*.conf" | awk -F %{buildroot} '{print $2}' > filelist.txt
find %{buildroot} -type f -name "*.conf" | awk -F %{buildroot} '{print $2}' > configfilelist.txt


%files -f filelist.txt
...
```

For regular files I can use the -f option to load the list in the generated file:

```
%files -f filelist.txt
```

I want to apply  the confilelist in a similar fashion.

```
%config(noreplace) xyz
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You're not really meant to have that many config files.

Comment: I'm packaging the software - not making it :S

Comment: and there are many modules and each module has a config file. its kind of tidy to manage while running...

Answer (score 1):

Add a little `awk` string concatenation magic and this should work. The rationale is that you now only define a single file for `%files -f` to parse.  To make the single file, I used the shell redirect operator for append rather than force write.

I swapped your order of instructions by defining configuration files first but that probably isn't necessary.

```
...
%install
unzip $RPM_SOURCE_DIR/APPLICATION-%{version}.zip -d %{buildroot}/

# add prefix to all config files
find %{buildroot} -type f -name "*.conf" | awk -F '%{buildroot}' '{print "%config(noreplace)", $2}' > filelist.txt

# add the rest
find %{buildroot} -type f ! -name "*.conf" | awk -F %{buildroot} '{print $2}' >> filelist.txt

%files -f filelist.txt
...
```

If you have docs you want to specify you should be able to do the same thing just with `{print "%doc", $2}` for the `awk` print string.

Great question, I'm all about these type of logical tricks because it becomes more ripe for CI/CD, less manual data entry, and longer lasting templates.